# SAPUI5 - Timeline growing button is running the select function each time it’s clicked

Tags: sapui5

I’m facing an issue with the default growing button in Timeline element. I have a select function attached to timeline and each timeline item can be clicked with the help of the select function.

However, I noticed each time I click on the growing button, it grows the displayed content AND it runs the timeline item that was hidden directly behind the growing button.

The work around I have in mind is hiding the original timeline growing button and instead I create a custom growing button that expands the displayed content each time it is clicked.

Appreciate any guidance if this is a bug with version I’m using (1.82) or I did something wrong in my code.

Sample (1.82):

XML:

```
<Timeline
        id="idTimeline"
        enableDoubleSided="false"
        growingThreshold="5"
        forceGrowing=“true”
        sortOldestFirst="true"
               showHeaderBar=“false”
               select=“onTimelineItemSelect”
        content="{/Messages}">
    <content>
        <TimelineItem
                id="idTemplateItem"
                dateTime="{date}"
                title="{title}"
               userNameClickable="false"
                text="{content}"
        userName="{emailAddress}">
        </TimelineItem>
    </content>
</Timeline>
```

JS:

```
onTimelineItemSelect: function(oEvent){
console.log(oEvent);
}
```

Comment: Try to put the "select" in the "<TimelineItem>".

Comment: This also happens in the latest version. That's probably why in 1.95 you can add an event handler directly to the item (`press` and `select`). I haven't found a workaround for lower versions :(